# Bitbucket Pipelines: Present a choice of deployment environment

Tags: bitbucket-pipelines

I have been tasked with presenting the developer with a manually triggered pipeline that provides the developer the option of which integration environment to deploy to.

For instance, we have 3 integration environments named 'savanna', 'desert' and 'jungle' available to integrate with. I would like the pipeline to halt after its initial steps have completed and offer the developer the choice of which integration environment to deploy. That way we can work on different aspects of the stack and test changes independently of other developers' work.

Is it possible to achieve this functionality Bitbucket pipelines? From what I can tell, Pipelines is only equipped to do deployments to static, ascending environments. Am I missing something?

Answer (score 0):

You can do the "choose your path" pipeline by making the choice steps be in parallel and triggered manually.

The limitations are however that they cannot have steps afterwards, since you need to complete all the parallel steps to continue, and that you cannot use the Bitbucket deployments on the steps as parallel deployments are not allowed, even if they would be all manual ones.

An alternative would be to do custom pipelines for each option where they choose to run the pipeline for their environment.

Comment: _parallel deployments are not allowed_ ? Are you sure? You mean to the same environment or something?

Comment: Defining the pipeline deployment variable for a parallel step. It was a feature request, but it was not taken up on https://jira.atlassian.com/browse/BCLOUD-18754

Comment: Isn't it fixed now? https://jira.atlassian.com/browse/BCLOUD-16650 My parallel deployments are actually automatic so I can't tell.

Comment: That is just manual parallel steps, deployments are still not supported. Tried about a month back

Comment: Yet, any related issue I can find is "fixed" https://jira.atlassian.com/browse/BCLOUD-16354 https://jira.atlassian.com/browse/BCLOUD-16787

Comment: All of them are closed due to being "duplicated" and clumped together with somewhat related ticket but none of them have this exactly feature. If you can find one that has work done in spring of '22 then it might have been added

Answer (score 0):

this won't work
Configuration error
Parallel steps can only contain deployments to a single environment type. Separate different types into their own parallel set.

https://jira.atlassian.com/browse/BCLOUD-18754

Answer (score 0):

I've wasted a day on this issue and seems like found a workaround.

We can do it if you put all your envs in a single env group(one of test, staging, production). It will affect layout in the Deployments tab, but in my case I don't really care.

Once it's done, here is an example of bitbucket-pipelines.yml:

```
# https://bitbucket-pipelines.atlassian.io/validator

definitions:
  steps:
    - step: &build
        name: Build
        image: node:16.20.0
        script:
          - .ci/build.sh

pipelines:
  branches:
    master:
    # We need this step because in Bitbucket first step must be automatic
    - step:
        name: Activate build button
        script: 
        - exit 0
    - step: 
        <<: *build
        trigger: manual
    - parallel:
        steps:
        - step:
            name: Activate deploy button
            script: 
            - exit 0
        - step: 
            name: Deploy to develop
            image: amazon/aws-cli:2.15.15
            deployment: develop
            trigger: manual
            script:
              - .ci/deploy.sh --env develop
        - step: 
            name: Deploy to staging-ec
            image: amazon/aws-cli:2.15.15
            deployment: staging-ec
            trigger: manual
            script:
              - .ci/deploy.sh --env staging-ec
        - step: 
            name: Deploy to prod-ec
            image: amazon/aws-cli:2.15.15
            deployment: prod-ec
            trigger: manual
            script:
              - .ci/deploy.sh --env prod-ec
```

The most important here is **first step which must be triggered automatically**, then all 3 buttons(Deploy to develop/staging/prod) will be clickable. This auto step can be build, like in my example, or fake that print some text.

[result](https://ibb.co/B4s4WHK)

Comment: Very important: All deployment environments in the parallel group must be of the same TYPE. You cannot have a mix of "Testing", "Staging" and "Production" types.

Answer (score -1):

While there are 3 underlying "static, ascending" environment categories, you can define up to 50 arbitrary environments in those categories. See https://bitbucket.org/blog/additional-deployment-environments-for-bitbucket-pipelines

BUT

You can't use them in parallel steps. Bitbucket yields this error

> **Configuration error**
>
> Parallel steps can only contain deployments to a single environment type. Separate different types into their own parallel set.

As @Randommm explained, Atlassian wrongly closed any issues relating to this, e.g. https://jira.atlassian.com/browse/BCLOUD-18754

STILL

You can "present a choice of deployment environment" if you trade-off multiple features. Namely

- Keeping track of deployments with custom environments. No re-deploy controls either.
- Using the `BITBUCKET_DEPLOYMENT_ENVIRONMENT` variable or any deployment variable in your scripts
- Reusing the deployment step, a.k.a. a clear bitbucket-pipelines.yml

Keep in mind that if you offer parallel manual deployments to staging environments, you could not continue the pipeline unless all steps were triggered. So I'd include the production deployment in that final parallel block.

```yaml
definitions:
  yaml-anchors:
    - &deploy-step
        script:
          - ./deploy.sh $BITBUCKET_DEPLOYMENT_ENVIRONMENT

pipelines:
  branches:
    main:
      - step:
          <<: *deploy-step
          name: Deploy Test
          deployment: test
          trigger: automatic

      - parallel:
        - step:
            name: Deploy Savanna
            # deployment: savanna  # don't
            trigger: manual
            script:
              - export CUSTOM_DEPLOY_VARS
              - ./deploy.sh savanna
        - step:
            name: Deploy Desert
            # deployment: desert  # don't
            trigger: manual
            script:
              - export CUSTOM_DEPLOY_VARS
              - ./deploy.sh desert
        - step:
            name: Deploy Jungle
            # deployment: jungle  # don't
            trigger: manual
            script:
              - export CUSTOM_DEPLOY_VARS
              - ./deploy.sh jungle
        - step:
            <<: *deploy-step
            name: Deploy Production
            deployment: production  # one is ok
            trigger: manual
```

This way it sort of works

[image]

But bitbucket will not acknowledge this steps as deployments to an environment

[image]

Comment: This is incorrect answer. Parallel steps can't use different deployment targets.

Comment: @deepdive thanks for the heads up. Updated with a "working version", sadly at the expense of major tradeoffs.