# Bitbucket Pipeline Deployments to selective environment

Tags: deployment, bitbucket, devops, cicd, bitbucket-pipelines

I have a bitbucket pipeline below. I'm trying to set it up so i can select which environment to deploy to. In my current setup i have to deploy to Dev before i can deploy to QA. I want to have the ability to deploy to either in any order. is this possible?

```
options:
  max-time: 5


image: node:latest

definitions: 
  steps:
    - step: &build
        name: Build
        caches:
          - node
        script:
          - Build Script
        artifacts:
         - *.zip
    - step: &deploy
        name: Deploy to Dev
        deployment: Dev
        trigger: manual
        runs-on:
         - self.hosted
         - windows
        script:
         - Deploy Script

pipelines:
  default:
    - parallel:
        - step: *build
    - step: *deploy
    - step:
          <<: *deploy
          name: Deploy to QA
          deployment: QA
          trigger: manual
```

I tried using parallel steps for each environment but that didn't change anything.

Comment: Bitbucket does not support parallel steps with deployments on more than one. if you can leave only one such step then you can put them in parallel to be run

Comment: Duplicate? https://stackoverflow.com/q/72821251/11715259