Running Bitbucket pipeline steps in parallel with specific dependencies
I'm working on configuring a Bitbucket pipeline for my project and I'm facing a challenge with defining the execution order of the steps. Here's the scenario:
I have a Bitbucket pipeline with four steps (step1, step2, step3, step4). What I want to achieve is to run step1 and step2 in parallel, and then, once both step1 and step2 are completed, run step3 and step4 in parallel.
image: node:18

pipelines:
  default:
    - parallel:
      - step:
          name: 'Build 1'
          script:
            - npm i 
            - npm run build
          artifacts:
            - 'public/'
      - step:
          name: 'Build 2'
          script:
            - npm i 
            - npm run build
            - mv public build2-public
          artifacts:
            - 'build2-public/'
      
    - step:
        name: 'Build 1 deploy'
        deployment: staging
        script:
          - cd public/
          - ls
        
    - step:
        name: 'Build 2 deploy'
        deployment: production
        script:
          - cd ve-public/
          - ls

How can I modify this configuration to achieve the desired behavior? I want step1 and step2 to run simultaneously, and only after both are finished, step3 and step4 should start executing in parallel.
Any insights or suggestions on how to structure my pipeline YAML configuration would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

If the question is about parallel deployments, it is a duplicate for https://stackoverflow.com/q/72821251/11715259

Easy, simply use two parallel blocks in series, each containing the desired steps:
pipelines:
  default:
    - parallel:
      - step: *step1
      - step: *step2
    - parallel:
      - step: *step3
      - step: *step4

For the specific use-case where some of those steps are deployments and you want them to potentially run in parallel: note there is a bitbucket pipelines shortcoming that prevents parallel deployments! See https://stackoverflow.com/a/72825050/11715259
The only known workaround is avoiding the default test,staging,production environments. You should use custom environments and all of them must be in the same "environment group" (either test or staging or production but not a mix). Then just write the pipeline as specified above. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/78136138/11715259
